# Are semi-direct products categorical (co)limits?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gr.group-theory

Products, are very elementary forms of categorical limits. My question is whether in the category of groups, semi-direct products are categorical limits.

As was pointed in:
http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/split-exact-sequences-and-semidirect-products/

Bourbaki (General Topology, Prop. 27) gives a universal property:

Let $f \colon N \to G$, $g \colon H \to G$ be two homomorphisms into a group $G$, such that $f(\phi_h(n)) = g(h)f(n)g(h^{-1})$ for all $n \in N$, $h \in H$. Then there is a unique homomorphism $k \colon N \rtimes H \to G$ extending $f$ and $g$ in the usual sense.

However, I remain unsatisfied. The condition $f(\phi_h(n)) = g(h)f(n)g(h^{-1})$ is a condition on elements of groups, rather than a condition that says that some diagram is commutative.

So the question remains: are semi-direct products in the category of groups categorical limits?

Comment: It's a certain colimit. Do you know the Grothendieck construction for fibrations?

Comment: Colimit? Are you sure about what you're saying? After all products are a particular case of semi-direct products, and they are limits not colimits. I don't know anything about Grothendieck's construction for fibrations...

Comment: Sure, colimit, because you describe maps *on* the semi-direct product. Actually this universal property of the semi-direct products in the special case of products does *not* give you the usual universal property of a categorical product: It gives you that group morphisms $N \times H \to G$ are given by pairs of group morphisms $N \to G$, $H \to G$ which commute pointwise. In other words, $N \times H = N * H / \langle\langle nhn^{-1} h^{-1} \rangle\rangle$, and here you already see the colimit. In a general semi-direct product, this commutator is twisted.

Comment: What's a reference for this? I still find this weird -- are you saying that in the category of groups products are limits AND colimits? That sounds very weird -- for example that would mean that products commute with colimits like free products, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't claim that the canonical map $N * H \to N \times H$ is an isomorphism. So you should be careful with your statements "products are limits and colimits". It's meant to be as I've written it above. A reference are the first pages of Serre's book *Trees*.

Comment: In any case, it can't be a limit since products and equalizers aren't fancy enough.

Comment: Semi-direct products involve an action $\phi: H \to Aut(N)$ in addition to the two factor groups $H,N$.  So the first step would be to figure out how to describe this action in purely category-theoretic terms, without referencing individual elements.  I don't know how to do this, but suspect that if one can achieve this, then describing the semi-direct product category-theoretically should be straightforward. 

Comment: Well, the real reason I asked the question is to know whether semi-direct products commute with inverse limits. Do you have any insight about that?

Comment: @Terry: Yes, and perhaps we should replace $N$ by a category for that purpose. That $\phi$ is just a functor $H \to N$. But meanwhile I don't think that there is a nice diagram of groups (built up out of the given data) whose colimit is $N \rtimes H$. Rather, I think it should be a *weighted colimit* or *bicolimit*.

Comment: In fact, the category of groups as a full subcategory of the category of small categories is in reality a $2$-category. If $f,f' : N \to G$ are group morphisms, then a morphism $f \to f'$ is some $x \in G$ such that $f' = x f x^{-1}$. And in the universal property of $N \rtimes H$ we require that $f \circ \phi(h)$ and $f$ are conjugated by $g(h)$. So I think that $N \rtimes H$ is a certain $2$-colimit.

Comment: @Makhalan: Is your real question about inverse limits? That is whether the inverse limit of semidirect products of $A_i$ and $B_i$ is a semidirect product of an inverse limit of $A_i$ and an inverse limit of $B_i$?

Comment: If that is your question, it should not be difficult to answer. 

Comment: Mark, it is indeed! Is it true? Do you have a reference, or can give a reason for it to be true?

Comment: I have not thought about it yet. I would expect the answer to be "no" because the product of inverse limit of $A_i$ and inverse limit of $B_i$ would too small that is $\lim A_iB_i\ne \lim A_i\lim B_i$). The other properties of semidirect products (that the inverse limit of $B_i$ is normal and that the intersection of the two inverse limits $\lim A_i$ and $\lim B_i$ is trivial hold). 

Comment: Hmm... I'm looking at the question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60750/profinite-completion-of-a-semidirect-product
in which you also participated. In Yiftach Barnea's answer, I believe that he assumes that inverse limits do commute with semi-direct products when he says that $\hat{G}\rtimes \hat{H}\cong \varprojlim (G\rtimes H)/(G_n\rtimes N)$. Would you agree with his usage, or do you think he is wrong?

Comment: An even bigger problem may be that if $A_iB_i$ form inverse system, the groups $A_i$ (or $B_i$) don't so the inverse limit $\lim A_i$ may not be defined. 

Comment: @Makhalan: That question was a year ago. It was important there, I think, that the question was about the profinite completions, not about arbitrary inverse limits. 

Comment: Let's put it in the simplest possible terms: is it possible to show that for $G$ and $H$ finitely generated, with an action $\phi_1:H\rightarrow Aut(G)$ which extends (by assumption) to an action $\phi_2:\hat{H}\rightarrow Aut(\hat{G})$ (where hat denotes profinite completion), it is true that $\hat{G}\rtimes \hat{H}$ is a profinite group?

Comment: Mark, I'm still trying to figure out whether it's true even in the context of that question. Yiftach Barnea didn't explain why that isomorphism is true.

Comment: Yes. It is exercise 5.6.2 in Ribes and Zalesski "Profinite groups". 

Comment: Semidirect products of profinite groups are special because a compactness argument lets you prove one can obtain the action as an inverse limit of actions of finite quotients. 

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a partial answer, summing up some of my comments.

The semi-direct product is not a limit, but rather it is a colimit. The reason is that the universal property cited above describes maps *on* the semi-direct product. In the special case that $\phi$ is the trivial action, the semi-direct product becomes the direct product $N \times H$ and the universal property is *not* just the usual universal property as a product, but rather as a representing object of the pairs of morphisms on $N,H$ which commute pointwise. In a general semi-direct product, this commutation is twisted by an action of $H$ on $N$.

So basically the idea is that we have the coproduct $N * H$ of the two groups (which is usually called the free product, which is quite unfortunate), and we impose the relation $h n h^{-1} = \phi_h(n)$. The universal property of $N \rtimes H$ is equivalent to the isomorphism

$$N \rtimes H = (N * H) / \{h n h^{-1}= \phi_h(n)\}_{h \in H, n \in N},$$

which exhibits $N \rtimes H$ as a special colimit of some diagram associated to $N,H,\phi$. However, this still uses elements in the relations. I think we cannot get rid of these elements, unless we use $2$-colimits. See below. Actually this isomorphism is used very often in group theory in order to recoqnize groups given by some presentation as a semi-direct product. For example, the dihedral group $D_n = \langle r,s : r^n = s^2 = 1, srs=r^{-1} \rangle$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$.

On the other hand, there is a purely category-theoretic construction which is due to Grothendieck: Let $I$ be a small category and $F : I \to \mathsf{Cat}$ be a diagram of small categories. The Grothendieck construction $\int^I F$ is the category of pairs $(i,x)$, where $i$ is an object of $I$ and $x$ is an object of $F(i)$. A morphism $(i,x) \to (j,y)$ is a pair $(a,f)$, consisting of a morphism $f : i \to j$ and a morphism $a : F(f)(x) \to y$ in $F(j)$. The composition is defined by the rule

$(a_2,f_2) \circ (a_1,f_1) = (a_2 \circ F(f_2)(a_1),f_2 \circ f_1)$.

Now if $H$ is a monoid, considered as a category with just one object $*$, and $F : H \to \mathsf{Cat}$ is a diagram such that $F(*)=N$ is just a monoid, then $F$ corresponds to a homomorphism of monoids $H \to \mathrm{End}(N)$ and the Grothendieck construction $\int^H N$ has just one object, thus corresponds to a monoid, namely what is usually called the semi-direct product $N \rtimes H$. This is shown by the multiplication rule above.

Back to the general case of a diagram $F : I \to \mathsf{Cat}$, the Grothendieck construction $\int^I F$ is the *lax 2-colimit* of $F$. I don't know the original reference right now, but a very comprehensive account on that is the Appendix A in "The stack of microlocal sheaves" by I. Waschkies. The choice of the morphism $a : F(f)(x) \to y$ in the definition above is precisely the reason for the "2" here. If it was the identity, we would get the usual colimit.

Thus, the semi-direct product $N \rtimes H$ is the lax $2$-colimit of the diagram $N : H \to \mathrm{Cat}$.

Comment: In your answere $H$ have to be a group (instead change $Aut(N)$ by $End(N)$). If $H$ and $N$ are internal groups, and we can internalizing $Aut(N)$ with a natural map $Aut(N)\times N\to N$ (this is possible in enought good enriched $V$-categories), then the semidirected composition  has a  internal formulation, furthermore I think that a action $\phi: L\to Aut(L)$ could be a pseudo-functor (consider groups as 2-cetegories, with one object on one (identity) morphism), then I guess that the semidirect-products is some kind of  a (co)lax-colimit ...(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: If you want, a traditional source on limits (and variations of these) on 2-categories is J. W. Gray "adjointness for 2-categories" (LNM 391). 

Answer (score 52):

There is (another ?) description of the crossed product in categorical terms.

Let ${\rm Mor}(Gp)$ be the category whose objects are homomorphisms of groups and morphisms are commutative diagrams. Let $C$ be the category of "groups acting on groups" whose objects are pairs of groups $(H,G)$ together with a homomorphism $H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$. Morphisms in this category are equivariant homomorphisms.

Now, there is a natural forgetful functor $T \colon {\rm Mor}(Gp) \to C$ which sends $H \to G$ to the pair $(H,G)$ with the homomorphism $H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$ given by conjugation. Now, almost by definition, the crossed product is the left-adjoint of this forgetful functor. Indeed, the left adjoint is easily seen to map $(H,G)$ with $H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$ to the inclusion $H \to G \rtimes H$.

Being a left-adjoint, the "crossed product" maps colimits to colimits.

Comment: This is a very concise categorical description!

Comment: Just checking: are the morphisms in $C$ just homomorphisms $(H, G) \to (H, G')$, or are we permitted to vary the group which is acting as well? That is, can we have a pair of group homomorphism $\phi: H \to H'$ and $\psi: G \to G'$ such that $\psi(h.g) = \phi(h).\psi(g)$ as a morphism in $C$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, $H$ need not be fixed.

Comment: No, but the map from G to G' can be equivariant with respect to phi.

Comment: Yes. It is phi x psi on the top arrow.

Comment: OK, the correct diagram is 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H\times G @>\phi\times \psi>> H'\times G'\\
@V \alpha V V@VV \alpha' V\\
G @>>\psi > G'
\end{CD}