# Hemi-semi direct product of racks or quandles

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, self-distributivity, quandles

In the category of racks (similarly quandles), instead of well-known semidirect product, we have the hemi-semi direct product construction as seen on [Wagemann & Crans](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4705).

As far as I know, semi direct product, categorically, has sense under colimit issue; [question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96078/are-semi-direct-products-categorical-limits).

I wonder if any clear algebraic or categorical explanation of hemi-semi direct products which makes this notion more coherent for me?

Also does this hemi-semi direct product have any relation with the normal semidirect product under the light of functor $\mathbf{Conj \colon Grp \to Rack}$?