# HNN-extension as a 2-colimit

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

In the spirit of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96078/are-semi-direct-products-categorical-colimits), it would be interesting to give a characterization of HNN extensions as a 2-colimit. If $G$ is a group and $\alpha:H \xrightarrow{\cong} K$ is an isomorphism between two subgroups of $G$, then I think that the HNN extension $G_{\alpha}$ has the following universal property: if we let $i_1:H \hookrightarrow G,i_2:K \hookrightarrow G$ be the canonical inclusions, then the set of group homomorphisms $G_{\alpha} \to T$ are in natural bijection to pairs $(f,t)$ where $f:G \to T$ is a group homomorphism and $t:f \circ i_2 \circ \alpha \Rightarrow f \circ i_1$ is a 2-morphism. Here we're considering $\mathbf{Grp}$ as a full subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$ which carries a standard 2-category structure.

I'm just wondering if this universal property can be phrased as some kind of 2-colimit.

Comment: I assume you are meaning to think of groups as one-object categories? It's not obvious to people who haven't thought about it this way before.

Comment: David, I think this is clear from the last sentence "we're considering Grp as a full subcategory of Cat".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your universal property is true, it exactly says that the HNN extension is the [coinserter](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inserter) of $(i_2 \circ \alpha,i_1) : H \rightrightarrows G$.